# How can I check if I'm connected to my database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to echo out "Connected" or Disconnected to see if im connected to my database or not.

This is my code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") 

mysqli_select_db($con,"online_ticket");
```

What if statements will be possible to test my connection?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You just had to google for **mysqli_connect** and found the answer is what @spencer7593 answered.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_connect` will return FALSE if a connection is not successful; it will return a connection handle if it is successful.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
```

> ```
> if (!$con) {
>     echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
>     echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
>     echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
>     exit;
> }
> ```

Answer (score -2):

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","username", 
                 "password", "db");
if (!$conn) {
    die(mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "<p>Connected!</p>";
```